# Language Processing: Determine if one paragraph is relevant to another paragraph

Tags: natural-language-processing, resource-request

**Context:** I want to determine if someone's written review contains content that is relevant to a paragraph that they are reviewing.

To do so, I am trying to determine if one paragraph is relevant to another paragraph. I initially tried to use TF-IDF to calculate the relevancy, but I think TF-IDF works well for determining if one paragraph is relevant to a whole set of paragraphs. I only want to determine if two paragraphs are relevant with each other.

What would be a good approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple approach can be:

- Calculate tf-idf vector for sentence 1 and 2.
- Calculate vector similarity (Cosine similarity) of these 2 vectors.

This is a general approach and works for any representational vector.

For a more complex one, check [semantic similarity with BERT](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert/) post from Keras blog.